# How can I fetch a dark mode favicon using Google's S2 API?

Tags: reactjs, web, google-api, favicon, google-search-api

I am trying to use Google's S2 API to get favicons for my app which integrates with other apps such as github and uses the urls of these to fetch the favicon (the requests are of the form [https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=${domain}&sz=${size}](https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=$%7Bdomain%7D&sz=$%7Bsize%7D)). My app has a dark mode and I was wondering whether there's a way to fetch a dark mode favicon over the S2 API or are there any other alternative APIs to consider

I have searched around forums to see if anyone else has had the issue and not found a solution yet.

I can't hardcode the favicons as there could be countless apps and so it doesn't scale.